# Dotnet Entity Framework Relationship Between Three Entities

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have an **Entity A** that **has many** (a list) of **Entity B** that **has many** of **Entity C** (I'd also like to have a separate instance of C, just one, It'd represent the winner, but I can solve that by just keeping it's ID, so *not necessary*).

**How do I connect the foreign keys between them?**

**How do I force that by deleting A, I delete all Bs, as well as all Cs dependent on it?** (easier approach -> they are chained and dependent of the previous)

**How do I keep Cs when I delete all As and Bs?** (more difficult approach -> B depends on A, but C doesn't depend on either)

**Entity A:**

```
namespace Server.Models
{
    [Table("Tournament")]
    public class Tournament
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("Max Number Of Disciplines")]
        public int MaxDisc { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entity B:

```
namespace Server.Models
{
    [Table("Discipline")]
    public class Discipline
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        [Column("Location")]
        public string Lokacija { get; set; }
        [Column("Max Number Of Contestants")]
        public int MaxContestants { get; set; }
        // [Column("Winner")]
        // [AllowNull]
        // public ContestantRef { get; set; } = default;
        [ForeignKey("Winner")]
        [AllowNull]
        public int WinnerID { get; set; } = default;
        [JsonIgnore]
        [Column("Tournament")]
        public Tournament TournamentRef { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Tournament")]
        public int TournamentID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Contestant> Contestants { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Entity C:**

```
namespace Server.Models
{
    [Table("Contestant")]
    public class Contestant
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("Surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [Column("Speed")]
        public int Speed { get; set; }
        [Column("Rank")]
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        [Column("Position")]
        public int Position { get; set; }
        [Column("Selected")]
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        [Column("Competing")]
        public bool Competing { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [Column("Discipline")]
        public Discipline DisciplineRef { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Discipline")]
        public int DisciplineID { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [Column("Tournament")]
        public Tournament TournamentRef { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Tournament")]
        public int TournamentID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**OnModelCreating:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Disciplines)
                .WithOne(dsc => dsc.TournamentRef)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Discipline>()
            .HasMany(dsc => dsc.Contestants)
            .WithOne(uc => uc.DisciplineRef)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

**Current Error:**
[On dotnet ef database update, in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZLlK.png)